# Power BI report and data set details

Tags: powershell, powerbi

We use the [Power BI online service](https://app.powerbigov.us/), we have a mix of premium and non-premium workspaces, every employee has a Power BI Pro license, and I am a Power BI Administrator on our tenant.

Our data warehouse team had been instructed to change the physical name of some columns in a data mart.  This change will break any reports that use the column.  I need to know which reports will be affected so I can either correct the reports or notify the report owners or users.

**Notifying users**

I can get the principal on a My Workspace workspace and I can get the admins for a group workspace.

I can query the activities log to identify who has used a report in the last 30 days or to see who created a report.

**Identifying the affected reports**

I have no way to see most of the content in our tenant.  Even as a Power BI Admin, I can't use the UI to navigate to another user's My Workspace.  Using PowerShell, I have used Get-PowerBIReport and Get-PowerBIDataset to inspect the objects.  I have also used Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod.  But the system doesn't appear to want to share information.

You'll see in the output, below, that Power BI won't tell me anything about the structure of the report or the dataset -- including whether or not they use the affected columns.  Is there some function in PowerShell that will expose more properties of these objects?  Is there another way to inspect objects in the Power BI online service?

script:

```
Login-PowerBI -Environment USGov

$rid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"

"Power BI Commandlets
"
"report"
$r = Get-PowerBIReport -Scope Individual -Id $rid
$r | Format-List -Property *

"
dataset"
$d = Get-PowerBIDataset -Scope Individual -Id $r.DatasetId
$d | Format-List -Property *

"

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod

"
"report"
$r = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "/reports/$rid" -Method Get
$r | ConvertFrom-Json | Format-List -Property *

"
dataset"
$dsid = ($r | ConvertFrom-Json).DatasetId
$d = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "/datasets/$dsid" -Method Get
$d | ConvertFrom-Json | Format-List -Property *
```

output:

```
Power BI Commandlets

report

Id        : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
Name      : Report Name
WebUrl    : https://app.powerbigov.us/groups/me/reports/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
EmbedUrl  : https://app.powerbigov.us/reportEmbed?reportId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002&config=lotsofrandomnumbersandletters
DatasetId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001



dataset

Id                               : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
Name                             : Report Name
ConfiguredBy                     : me@DEPARTMENT.GOV
DefaultRetentionPolicy           : 
AddRowsApiEnabled                : False
Tables                           : 
WebUrl                           : https://app.powerbigov.us/groups/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/datasets/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
Relationships                    : 
Datasources                      : 
DefaultMode                      : 
IsRefreshable                    : True
IsEffectiveIdentityRequired      : False
IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired : False
IsOnPremGatewayRequired          : False
TargetStorageMode                : Abf
ActualStorage                    : 
CreatedDate                      : 2/21/2024 7:11:28 PM
ContentProviderType              : 



Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod

report

@odata.context : http://wabi-us-gov-virginia-redirect.analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#reports/$entity
id             : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
reportType     : PowerBIReport
name           : Report Name
webUrl         : https://app.powerbigov.us/groups/me/reports/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
embedUrl       : https://app.powerbigov.us/reportEmbed?reportId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002&config=lotsofrandomnumbersandlet 
                 ters
isOwnedByMe    : True
datasetId      : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
users          : {}
subscriptions  : {}



dataset

@odata.context                   : http://wabi-us-gov-virginia-redirect.analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#datasets/$ent
                                   ity
id                               : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
name                             : Report Name
webUrl                           : https://app.powerbigov.us/groups/me/datasets/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
configuredBy                     : me@DEPARTMENT.GOV
isRefreshable                    : True
isEffectiveIdentityRequired      : False
isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired : False
isOnPremGatewayRequired          : False
targetStorageMode                : Abf
createReportEmbedURL             : https://app.powerbigov.us/reportEmbed?config=lotsofrandomnumbersandletters
qnaEmbedURL                      : https://app.powerbigov.us/qnaEmbed?config=lotsofrandomnumbersandletters
upstreamDatasets                 : {}
users                            : {}
queryScaleOutSettings            : @{autoSyncReadOnlyReplicas=True; maxReadOnlyReplicas=0}
```

If the correct answer is, "It can't be done," I'll mark that as correct following sufficient discussion.  I suspect future SO readers who are Power BI admins will benefit from knowing this.